# Best jQuery Plugin Structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, prototype

I am trying to write a **good** jQuery Plugin structure. I am trying to follow "best practices" from jQuery.com and others.

But I am little bit confused about prototype.

Should I use it or not? And Is the actual structure looks good or terrible?

Thanks !

```
(function( $ ){
    var defaults = { /* ... */ },
    publicMethods = {
        add: function(options){
            var $this = $(this);
            // ...
            return $this;
        }
    },
    privateMethods = {
        init: function(options) {
            var $this = $(this);
            return $this;
        },
        click: function() {
            //...
        }
    };
    $.fn.tooltip = function(method) {
        var args = arguments;

        $(this).each(function() {
            if ( publicMethods[method] ) {
                return publicMethods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( args, 1 ));
            } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
                return privateMethods.init.apply( this, args );
            } else {
                $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
            }   
        });
    };
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: *"I am little bit confused about prototype."* What are you confused about? The only place where you're using it, you're only using it as a means of getting to the `.slice()` method. If you're following "best practices", then is there some reason you'd think your code would be terrible?

Comment: Oh no I am just talking about the structure of the code !
I discovered "prototype" recently, so my question is should I still use my "method calling logic $.fn.tooltip ..." or start using prototypes instead ?

Comment: If this helps you http://heera.it/patterns-in-jquery-plugin-writin

Comment: jQuery just makes `fn` a reference to the `prototype` object, presumably because it's shorter. So when you do `$.fn` you're really doing `$.prototype`. Try this: `alert($.fn === $.prototype);`

Comment: @amnotiam Thanks That is good to know. But my real question is should I use prototypes inside of the plugin like tooltip.protype ... ?

Comment: That would be useful only if your `tooltip` function is used as a constructor. Typically as a jQuery plugin, you're only interested in using the object created from the `jQuery` constructor, rather than creating your own objects from the plugin. There may be occasion to use a constructor somewhere in your plugin code, but it typically wouldn't be the actual plugin function itself.

Comment: @amnotiam Thank you! Could you post that as an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to using the `.prototype` of the `tooltip` function, that would be useful only if the tooltip function is going to be invoked as a constructor.

Typically as a jQuery plugin, you're only interested in using the object created from the `jQuery` constructor, rather than creating your own objects from the plugin function.

There may be occasion to use a constructor somewhere internally in your plugin code, but it typically wouldn't be the actual plugin function itself.